# Error when using Fill Sinks (wang & liu) in Saga in QGIS

Tags: qgis, error

I am using fill sinks (wang & liu) from Saga in QGIS.
When I run the tool I am having the following error:

> Loading resulting layers The following layers were not correctly
>   generated.
>
> - C:/AGMEE/Workspace
>     Saga/DEM_FlowDirection.sdat
> - C:/AGMEE/Workspace
>     Saga/DEM_WatershedBasins.sdat
>
> You can check the 'Log Messages
>   Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the
>   execution of the algorithm.

However, when I run the tool the Filled Dem parameter is executed but the Flow Direction and Watershed Basins are not.

I am using the last version of OSGeo4W Network.

Do you know something about it?

Comment: Have you checked the `Log Messages Panel` to see what the error message says?

Comment: Have you tried running it in 3.8.3 instead of 3.10.1? its probably just another bug.